# Calculate the maximum value of $\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$ where $a, b, c > 0$ and $abc = a + b + c + 2$.

Tags: inequality, summation, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positives such that $abc = a + b + c + 2$. Caculate the maximum value of $$\large \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2 + c^2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2 + a^2}}$$

This problem is adapted from a recent competition. Here's what I got, and I am pretty proud of it. (Actually not.)

$$abc = a + b + c + 2$$

$$\iff abc + (ab + bc + ca) + (a + b + c) + 1 = ab + bc + ca + 2(a + b + c) + 3$$

$$\iff (a + 1)(b + 1)(c + 1) = (a + 1)(b + 1) + (b + 1)(c + 1) + (c + 1)(a + 1)$$

$$\frac{1}{a + 1} + \frac{1}{b + 1} + \frac{1}{c + 1} = 1$$

And I'm done.

Comment: From which competition is it?

Comment: The entrance exam to Phan Bội Châu gifted high school in province Nghệ An. I live in province Vũng Tàu, which is far away from there.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will give it a look.

Comment: Good luck! (If you're not from Vietnam.)

Comment: I posted a solution, hope you like it! Keep posting nice problems!

Comment: Can you give a link where these problems for entrance can be found? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, I can, but the whole site is in Vietnamese and there're tons of these tests because all students who want to get to higher education (the 10th grade) need to take a test. This happens across the country within a month or longer. The tests are similar to each other but that is not the case for gifted high schools.

Comment: It doesn't matter, I hope Google Translate will be my friend :)

Comment: Here's one more thing: The tests that were given to standard students and gifted students are different, the site doesn't separate them. So watch out for the word: "Chuyên". And the test papers can sometimes be too pixelated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94808/discussion-between-le-thanh-dt-and-math-here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=\frac{y+z}{x}$ and $b=\frac{x+z}{y},$ where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positives.

Thus, $c=\frac{x+y}{z}$ and by AM-GM twice we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{xy}{\sqrt{y^2(y+z)^2+x^2(x+z)^2}}\leq$$
$$\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{xy}{\sqrt{2xy(x+z)(y+z)}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{xy}{(x+z)(y+z)}}\leq$$
$$\leq\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x}{x+z}+\frac{y}{y+z}\right)=\frac{3}{2\sqrt2}.$$
The equality occurs for $x=y=z=1,$ which says that we got a maximal value.

Comment: I realized that. I have deleted my previous comment. Great solution, I have to say!

Comment: Very nice solution dear Michael!

Answer (score 2):

So, by Cauchy-Schwarz, we have $a^2+b^2 \geq (a+b)^2/2$, so we just have to prove that

$\displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{a+b} \leq 3/4$ (It's obvious that this maximum occurs when $a=b=c=2$, I will prove it.)

Letting, $a=2k,b=2l,c=2m$ we have to prove that $\displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{k+l} \leq 3/2$ subject to the condition $4klm=k+l+m+1$.

By expanding and letting $k+l+m=p, kl+lm+mk, klm=r$ we have to prove that $3pq-3r \geq 2p^2+2q$.

Substituting $r=(p+1)/4$, we have to prove that $q(3p-2) \geq \frac{8p^2+3p+3}{4}$.

Now, it is known that $q^2 \geq 3pr=\frac{3p^2-3p}{4}$ so it suffices to show that $\sqrt{3p^2+3p}\cdot (3p-2) \geq \frac{8p^2+3p+3}{2}$ which is equivalent to :

$(p-3)(44p^3+48p^2-9p+3)$.

By AM-GM, $p+1=4r \leq 4p^3/27$ so easily $p \geq 3$.

So, $p-3 \geq 0$ and $44p^3+48p^2-9p+3 >48p^2-9p=p(48p-9)>0$ and the problem is solved.